# Implementing Deque using 3 Stacks (Amortized time O(1))

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, stack, deque, amortized-analysis

I have this question for howmework:

Implement a Deque using 3 Stacks. The Deque have those operations : InsertHead, InsertTail, DeleteHead,DeleteTail. Prove that the amortized time for each operation is O(1).

What I've tried is to look at the problem as Hanoi problem. 
So lets call the Stacks as: L(left), M (middle), R(right).

Pseudo-code Implementations:

```
InsertHead(e):
     L.push(e);

DeleteHead(e):
     L is empty:

       while R is not empty:
          pop and insert the element to M;
       pop M;
       while M is not empty:
         pop and insert the element to R;

     L is not empty:    
       L.pop(e);
```

InsertTail and DeleteTail are on the same principle of the above implementations.
How can I prove that the amortized time is O(1)? 
because there can be N elements in L and the wile loop will take O(n), now if I'll call the deleteHead N times to calculate an amortized time the complexity will not be O(n^2)?

can someone help me how can I prove that the above implementations take O(1) in amortized time?

[image: Deque from 3 Stacks: DeleteHead operation of Deque]

Comment: Use two stacks: L and R.  When attempting to pop(L) on empty L divide all elements from R equally between L and R (you will need third stack for this operation).

Comment: why divide R equally between L and R and not as the way I did?

Comment: Because you won't get O(1) this way (what happens if L is always empty?)

Comment: ok, lets say that I know what is the number of elements in R and I divide it equally between L and R using the third stack (as the question require) so If I have N elements in R, still.. I need to loop over N elements in R, to divide equally the elements between L and M, then I need to move on the elements of M to transfer them back to R. right? now if I'll try to call DeleteHead N times, it's still remain O(n^2). so how the amortized time can be O(1)?!

Comment: Egor and n.m I've edited my question and added an image which describes your solution.. how it can be o(1)?

Comment: Count how many times in total you will have to do the stack division when you push N elements and then pop them from the other end, and how many elements you will move each time.

Answer (score 2):

We proceed using the [potential method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potential_method); define

`Phi = C |L.size - R.size|`

For some constant `C` for which we will pick a value later. Let `Phi_t` denote the potential after `t` operations. Note that in a "balanced" state where both stacks have equal size, the data structure has potential 0.

The potential at any time is a constant times the difference in the number of elements in each stack. Note that `Phi_0 = 0` so the potential is zero when the structure is initialised.

It is clear that a push operation increases the potential by at most `C`. A pop operation which does not *miss* (i.e. where the relevant stack is nonempty) also alters the potential by at most `C`. Both of these operations have true cost 1, hence they have amortised cost `1 + C`.

When a pop operation occurs and causes a *miss* (when the stack we want to pop from is empty), the true cost of the operation is `1 + 3/2 * R.size` for when we are trying to pop from `L`, and vice versa for when we are popping from `R`. This is because we move half of R's elements to M and back, and the other half of R's elements to L. The `+1` is needed because of the final pop from `L` after this rebalancing operation is done.

Hence if we take `C := 3/2`, then the pop operation when a *miss* occurs has amortised cost 1, because the potential reduces from `3/2 * R.size` to 0 due to the rebalancing, and then we may incur an additional cost of `3/2` from the pop which occurs after the rebalance.

In other words, each operation has an amortised cost bounded by a constant.

Finally, because the initial potential is 0, and the potential is always nonnegative, each operation is amortised cost O(1), as required.

Comment: I have a question. I completely agree with you on the analysis of the pop amortized cost. My problem is : push operation as a constant cost of 1, but potential can either move +k or -k. So the amortized cost, if k is 3/2, can be negative, which does not permit us to show that potential can never be negative. Isn't this troubling ?